# Ruby on Rails with Amazon ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i am just wondering why it's hard to run my ROR app on aws Elaticbeanstalk? My apps works fine on localhost but when i deploy on aws it shows me this error

[image]

I would like to know how to properly deploy an rails app on aws, also how does the gems are installed by aws. Following are some of my config:

.ebextensions/ruby.config

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS
    value: "1"
  - option_name: BUNDLE_PATH
    value: "vendor/bundle"

packages:
  yum:
    git: []
```

My routes:

```
Apps2::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks" }

  resources :posts

  root :to => 'posts#index'
end
```

Also i would like to know is there any way we can debug our application once deployed on aws? Thanks

Comment: If this were heroku at after deploying for the first time I'd run `rake db:create && rake db:migrate` have you done that? Did you use this for the deploy? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html

Comment: @AdamT u mean create db and migrate table? Yes i already done that. My localhost and aws share same rds database. Any other way i can debug this issues

Comment: what do the logs show?

Comment: @AdamT how can i enable the log? Aws keep showing default error page

Comment: guessing it's something like this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html

Answer (score 1):

You will want to check your production logs:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html

or be a little more direct and just have the app display the complete error rather than the error page (config/environments/production.rb):

```
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

(this is not good for production but very easy for debugging to get you going)

Answer (score 1):

> how does the gems are installed by aws [sic]

After pushing your application to Elastic Beanstalk, gems in the Gemfile are automatically installed. [source](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git)

> Also i would like to know is there any way we can debug our
>   application once deployed on aws?

SSH into your instance, and navigate to /var/app/current/logs to inspect your Ruby on Rails logs.